# Can we wrap routes implemented using ui-router inside an Angular Directive?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-route

We are looking at implementing an Angular Wizard. Though routes are the best way to do it, we would like the wizard to be presented in such a way that it is usable as a directive.

For eg, someone must be able to use the wizard like  (with sufficient options) and all the ui-router logic in between should work.

Is it possible in Angular to wrap the ui-router logic into a directive? Can we declare directives whose dependency is the ui-router (or something like the routeProvider) and start routing inside a directive?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't do that wizard inside ng-view?

Comment: Yes already done it, but the better way is to use routes because a wizard has paths based on what is selected in it sometimes. The question isnt particular to developing a wizard. It is more of whether this is possible in Angular and if not, then is it by Angular design, or there hasnt been a use case yet